# How to prevent Canvas app from opening in a new browser tab in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning, canvas

We are developing a Canvas application configured to run from the Case Layout Page. The application is intended to allow the user to click on certain elements within its UI without opening a new browser tab. However, when running in Lightning Experience, clicking any part of the application results in the application being opened in a new browser tab, which is not desired behavior. The cause looks to be a CSS “mask” overlaying the Canvas application.

Ideally, we’d like to remove the mask client-side, however we don’t see a way to do this from the Canvas JavaScript API. From the Canvas Developer Guide, it seems like a custom Apex class implementing the Canvas.CanvasLifecycleHandler interface could potentially be an option. However, we don’t want to put a lot development effort into implementing, if this doesn’t provide the capability to modify the CSS “mask”.

**Is there a client-side mechanism for removing the CSS mask, or is the custom Apex class a solution? Without modifying the intended behavior of our Canvas application or it’s location, are there other solutions that we should consider?**

Note that our Canvas application works as intended when running in Salesforce Classic mode.

Comment: "From the Canvas Developer Guide, it seems like a custom Apex class implementing the Canvas.CanvasLifecycleHandler interface could potentially be an option". Could you point me to a link where I can find how to remove that mask using Apex class. I don't want to use visualforce page solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page layout seems to be setting `watermark="true"` for your canvas app. I don't see an option to turn that off, but there could be a few other options.

1. Include the Canvas app in a different location in the Lightning Record Page (outside of the Classic page layout) through the Lightning App Builder. This would let you include custom Lightning components too.
2. Create a Visualforce page that includes the Canvas app, and add that to the page layout.

   ```
   <apex:page standardController="Case">
       <apex:canvasApp developerName="app_name_here" />
   </apex:page>
   ```

Comment: Thanks! We ended up landing on the same solution as your 2nd option of creating a Visualforce page that includes the Canvas app.